# Installed ubuntu 14.04 on mac now I want to go back to osx

Tags: 14.04, mac, macbook, macosx, macbook-pro

I installed ubuntu 14.04 to my MacBook Pro and now I want to return to OS X but I deleted it while I was Installing ubuntu. And I am not a great tech guru either so can someone help me in the easiest way?

Comment: Buy a new OSX copy, that's the only way.

Comment: Did you not get disks with yours?  If not, like Eduardo said, time to buy a new copy.  Mine came with recovery disks a few years back....

Answer (score 3):

You will need a friend with OSX/Mac

They will need to download the Yosemite installer from the app store and make a bootable USB.

You can then use that usb to boot on your mac and install OSX.

[This](http://osxdaily.com/2014/10/16/make-os-x-yosemite-boot-install-drive/) is a good guide I've used before to install OSX.

Comment: Thank you =3 I'll try doing that later. I am going to visit a friend with an OS X device about a month later

Comment: Please upvote / accept if it works for you :)